# Uniform authorization and registration between MVC and Web API projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The Web API project is already completely written and it uses `User.Identity`. There's also an MVC site that uses `SimpleMembership`. Is it possible to make both projects make use of the same user data for registration and authorization?